# How to normalize data by assigning NaN or zero to missing rows in matlab?

Tags: matlab, nan

I use matlab 2014b. 
I have a wrong program step. I don't know what is wrong with my script.
I have data per 10 minutes. time and value RR.

```
09/10/2014 3:00    0
09/10/2014 3:10    0
09/10/2014 3:30    0.4
09/10/2014 3:50    0.4
09/10/2014 4:00    0.4
09/10/2014 4:10    0.4
09/10/2014 4:20    0.4
09/10/2014 4:30    0.4
10/10/2014 4:40    0.4
09/10/2014 4:50    0.4
09/10/2014 5:00    0.4
09/10/2014 5:10    0.4
09/10/2014 5:20    0.4
....
```

Data consists of 12176x2 cell

It can be seen that after the second row there is no a time information nor data for 3:20 a.m. I want to get data per 10 minutes with empty data filled with 0 / NAN.
I use matlab 2014b and there is no `retime` function in that version. 
I say thank you to anyone who has tried to help and advise.

```
times = out(:,1);
dn = datenum(times);
min_time = min(dn);
min_time_dv = datevec(min_time);
min_time_dv(5) = floor(min_time_dv(5) / 10) * 10;  
first_slot_dn = datenum(min_time_dv);
max_time = max(dn);
max_time_dv = datevec(max_time);
max_time_dv(5) = floor(max_time_dv(5) / 10) * 10;  
last_slot_dn = datenum(max_time_dv);
ten_mins_as_days = 1 / (24 * 60/10);
slot_dns = first_slot_dn : ten_mins_as_days : last_slot_dn;
slot_ds = datestr(slot_dns);
times_minutes = [cellstr(slot_ds(1:end,:))]; 
slot_ds = datestr(slot_dns);
[~, slot_idx] = histc(dn, slot_dns);
mean_RR1 = accumarray(slot_idx, RR(:), [length(slot_dns),1],@nanmean);
output1 = [cellstr(slot_ds(1:end,:)), num2cell(mean_RR1)];
```

I wrote a script and it has normalized well per 10 minutes. But the missing time was not filled by NAN. There was an error in normalizing the NAN values. Is there a suggestion to fix it?

I expect the results to be like this:

```
09/10/2014 3:00 0
09/10/2014 3:10 0
09/10/2014 3:20 NAN
09/10/2014 3:30 0.4
10/10/2014 3:40 NAN
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using MATLAB's [ismember](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function, which is very efficient in my experience.

```
time_input = ['09/10/2014 3:00'; '09/10/2014 3:10'; '09/10/2014 3:30'];
time_gaps = datetime(time_input,'InputFormat','dd/MM/yyyy H:mm');
L = length(time_gaps);
values_gaps = repelem(0.1,L);

% create normalized time vector
time_norm = datetime((time_gaps(1):minutes(10):time_gaps(end))');

% locate gaps by comparing the time vectors
[~, loc] = ismember(time_gaps,time_norm);

% create normalized value vector + fill at locations
values_norm = NaN(length(time_norm),1);
values_norm(loc) = values_gaps;
```

I did not bother using your code, as it was confusing to me. I use R2018b with datetime function, but it should be available to you in R2014b.